# Model doesn't save if confirm password used in Yii2

Tags: yii2, rules, password-confirmation

Im my project I have issues with using the confirm password.

I don't have confirm password field in my database, I assume that is the reason I am getting this error.

**My Model**

```
     public $user_password_hash_repeat;
     public $agree;
     public $user_search;



//  const SCENARIO_LOGIN = 'login';
    const SCENARIO_REGISTER = 'signup';
    const SCENARIO_CREATE = 'create';
    const SCENARIO_UPDATE = 'update';
    const SCENARIO_PASSWORD = 'password';
    const SCENARIO_NEWPASSWORD = 'newpassword';


    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'sim_user';
    }

    /** 
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['user_email', 'user_fname'], 'required', 'on' => 'update'], // on Update Method scenario
            [['user_email', 'user_fname', 'user_password_hash'], 'required', 'on' => 'create'], // on create method scenario
            [['user_fname','user_email','user_password_hash','user_password_hash_repeat'], 'required', 'on' => 'signup'], // on signup scenario
            [['user_password_hash'],'required' ,'on' => 'newpassword'],// repeat password scenario    
            ['agree','required','requiredValue' => 1,'message' => 'Tick the box', 'on' => 'signup'],// on signup scenario
            ['user_password_hash','match','pattern'=>'$\S*(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*[\d])\S*$','message'=>'Password must have atleast 1 uppercase and 1 number '],
            ['user_password_hash', 'string', 'min' => 6],
            ['user_password_hash_repeat', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'user_password_hash', 'skipOnEmpty' => false],
            [['user_email'],'email'],
            [['user_company', 'user_suspended', 'user_deleted'], 'integer'],
            [['user_email'], 'string', 'max' =>255],
            ['user_email','unique','targetClass'=> '\app\models\SimUser','on'=> 'create'], //create method scenario for unique email
            ['user_email','unique','targetClass'=> '\app\models\SimUser','on'=> 'signup'],// signup method scenario for unique email
            ['user_email','unique','targetClass'=> '\app\models\SimUser','on'=> 'update'],//update method scenario for unique email
            [['user_fname', 'user_lname'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
            [['user_auth_key'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
            [['user_access_token'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            ['user_email', 'exist', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_PASSWORD]


        ];
    }
```

**Controller action**

```
public function actionSignup()
    {
        $company = new Company(); 
        $model = new SimUser(['scenario' => SimUser::SCENARIO_REGISTER]);
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())&& $model->validate() && $company->load(Yii::$app->request->post())&& $company->validate()) {
           // var_dump($model); exit()
            $model->setPassword($model->user_password_hash);
            $model->generateAuthKey();      
           // $company->save();

            $model->company_id = 1; 
              try{
                    $model->save();
                }catch (Exception $ex) {
                    var_dump($ex->getMessage()); exit();
                }

            if ($model->save()){
                $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
                $authorRole = $auth->getRole('staff');
                $auth->assign($authorRole, $model->user_id);
            }
          \Yii::$app->user->login($model);
          return $this->redirect(['/site/index']);  
        }

        return $this->render('signup', [
            'model' => $model,
            'company' => $company,

        ]);
    }
```

If you see the rules, I have set user_password_hash_repeat to be skipOnEmpty = false, which forces the user to type in this field. If I set that to true and just type the password and submit it submits the form and saves the model successfully.

I have also tried using the required for the user_password_hash_repeat, I end up not able to save the model.

What is wrong in my rules setup?

Thank you!!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I don't get any error , It just doesn't save my model...

Comment: Try to use `$model->scenario = 'signup';` before saving your model.

Comment: Show your related controller/action

Comment: I have added the controller action..

Comment: @KamranKhatti that did not help .. tried that now

Comment: can you put that code in try catch to print the error message so that we can get better error message.

Comment: which code to put in try and catch method?

Comment: put the whole `if` statement in try block print message in catch  also for now `comment` `render` section.

Comment: also for just debugging use `if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), '')) {` only skip `$company` model for now and save only `$model` check if it works or not.

Comment: Yeah I have skipped $company for now.. I trie it..but not showing any error check my controller action i have updated it

Comment: Try this very basic code see if it works or not `$model = new SimUser();
        $model->setScenario('signup');
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), '')) {
            if ($model->save()) {
                die('Succes');
            } else {
                die('Error');
            }
        }`

Comment: As expected throws an error...

Comment: put scenario `'on' => 'singup'` after `'skipOnEmpty' => false` in  `user_password_hash_repeat` rule

Comment: no change.. It still returns error only

Comment: the issue is in rules send table structure I need to fix it at my end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127312/discussion-between-mohan-prasad-and-kamran-khatti).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing second parameter of `load model`, pass empty string as second parameter.

**Replace this**

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())
```

**With this**

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), '') //Note: Pass second parameter as empty string
```

so your `if` condition would look like

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(),'')&& $model->validate() && $company->load(Yii::$app->request->post(),'')&& $company->validate()) {
```

hope this works.

Comment: I added them..when I add this it submits the form but doesn't save anything and renders back the same page.. it doesn't even redirect my page